# Cannot find name 'process' angular 5

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, process

After seeing all the answers, nothing helped me...

**baseUrl.interceptor.ts**

```
 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let baseurl = process.env.baseurl || 'http://test.com/users';
    console.log(baseurl);

    return next.handle(req);
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
]
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.1.0",

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    ...
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
```

And an error below:
 [image]

Please, help me somebody...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`process` is a variable that gives you access to your server.

In no case you are supposed to use it in your Angular application : it's made to be used on your Node server.

If you do that, this means that anyone who is running your application can see your environment variables. That includes, for instance, your API keys.

Comment: I agree, `process.env` is typically server-side (Node) code, it has absolutely nothing to do in an Angular application.

Comment: Okey, why it works fine in my VueJS app where i also use 'process'...? 
(without SSR)

Comment: Because VueJS is a library that help you create HTML views that your server will serve, while Angular creates HTML views that will replace the content of your index.html.

Comment: So do you know other solutions? May be add in webpack.config?

Comment: Nothing, you don't expose your process variables ! In Angular, you have the `environment` files for that.

Comment: It is necessary for me for fast change of process.env in linux server (not in environments/environmets.ts). It answer helped me so much, thanks! I did that in webpack.config :)

Comment: **Seriously don't do that**. I'm not joking around or anything, you really need to **not use the process variable**. Use the environments, it doesn't matter if it's slower to edit, you must **not use this variable**.

Comment: This will be the 4th time I'm telling it, at one time I will just stop and let you get hacked. **YOU DON'T EXPOSE YOUR SERVER ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES INTO YOUR APPLICATIONS !** If you want a simple url, then you use `environment.ts`, and this is the right way to do it in Angular.

Comment: what about other global variables ? like  API SERVER URL ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm setting up my environment within Angular with a dotenv file, I don't know if this is the same situation you have. That's where I'm requesting my env vars.

I set up the environment files dinamically with a node script before compilation time with `fs.writeFile`. There I can get the `process.env` and thanks to the 'dotenv' npm package also.